# what kind of $x$ fits into $argsort(x)$=$ argsort(argsort(x))$?

Tags: order-theory, sorting

For a 1-d array, what kind of x gives you `argsort(x) == argsort(argsort(x))` ? sorted array would be a trivial soliton. but you can have not sorted array like `[1, 0, 2]` or `[1, 0, 2, 3]`

`argsort` is function that returns the indices that would sort an array.

for example. given `x=[1, 0, 10]`, `argsort(x)` would return `[1, 0, 2]` which represents the ordering of original array.

i'm really interested.

```
sorted_array = np.arange(10)

np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.argsort(sorted_array), 
                    np.argsort(np.argsort(sorted_array)))

# or
semi_sorted = [1, 0, 2]
np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.argsort(semi_sorted), 
                 np.argsort(np.argsort(semi_sorted)))

# or 

semi_sorted = [1, 0, 2, 3]

np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.argsort(semi_sorted),
               np.argsort(np.argsort(semi_sorted)))
```

what type of arrays fits in the criteria?

Comment: it seems to be array that goes with one direction or have one pivot point would be the character, but why?

Comment: What is argsort?

Comment: sorry i didn't explain, it's an operation returns the indices that would sort the array. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy-without-sorting-array-twice/

argsort(argsort(x)) giving order of numbers in x - I present a proof at http://www.berkayantmen.com/rank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your $\operatorname{argsort}$ correctly, then $\operatorname{argsort}(x)$ takes as input a finite sequence of distinct numbers -- that is a map from $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ to distrinct numbers -- and produces a *permutation* $\sigma$ such that $x\circ\sigma$ is an *increasing* sequence.

Therefore, the *fixed points* of $\operatorname{argsort}$ are the permutations $\sigma$ where $\sigma\circ\sigma$ is an increasing sequence. But $\sigma\circ\sigma$ is always a permutation, and the only permutation that is increasing is the identity, so the fixed points are the $\sigma$ with $\sigma\circ\sigma=\rm Id$, or in other words permutations of order $1$ or $2$. That is exactly the permutations that are products of disjoint transpositions.

This is relevant because your equation $\operatorname{argsort}(x) = \operatorname{argsort}(\operatorname{argsort}(x))$ calls for $\operatorname{argsort}(x)$ to be a fixed point of $\operatorname{argsort}$.

Thus, the solutions to your equation are exactly the ones that you can make by:

- Start with an increasing sequence.
- Select zero or more non-overlapping *pairs* of elements in the sequence (not necessarily neighbors), and swap each pair.

Comment: my guess is actually something like this, 1, arrays have single direction increase/decrease, (which is sorted) 2, arrays can change direction, but make sure, when direction changes, the minimum/maximum is bigger/smaller than the maximum/minimum of the previous direction.

Comment: @yupbank: Why do you keep _guessing_ after I posted an answer that tells you exactly what the solutions are?

Comment: lol.. sorry, i shouldn't. so the idea of non-overlapping pairs, basically says i can't swap the same element twice right? which can translate into a 2d matrix transformation which  have only one 1 per column and per row and 0 else where?

Comment: @yupbank: Yes to the first part of that comment, no to the second part. The second part describes an _arbitrary_ permutation, but you can only use those particular permutations where, if `p[i]=j` then `p[j]=i` too.

Comment: actually, elements in X don't have to be distinct.

Comment: @yupbank: then I think I'm missing a definition of what the argsort function does in that case.